# How to add data to an already existing KEY in a List of Dictionary in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

So I have a list of dictionaries below

```
users = [
          {
            "username" : "Sarthak",
            "password" : "Sartagarwal1",
            "faves" : ["Shake It Off", "Clocks"]
          },
          {
            "username" : "Sharma21",
            "password" : "Shame200521",
            "faves" : ["Roar", "Shake It Off", "Believer"]
          }
        ]
```

And what I want to do is let the user create an account. So I ask them for a Username and a Password. After that, I want to create a new dictionary for that new user. But I don't know how to add that.

I have tried using the update() method and also searched online. But I just can't figure it out, I do have a JSON file where all this data is saved and I saw the dump() function but I don't really know if I am supposed to use that in my certain situation.

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me out :)

Thank you in advance and Have a great day!

Comment: `users` is a list not a dictionary, so you should create a new dictionary that has `{keys:values}` and then add it into your `users` list using `users.append(new_user)`

Comment: To make your question more clear provide expected outcome to the community

Comment: Please show your account creation code and we'll be able to see what, if anything, you're doing wrong

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

users is a list instead of dictionary here. You can use the append method:

```
users.append(
    {
        "username" : "user1",
        "password" : "pass1",
        "faves" : ["Shake It Off", "Clocks"]
    }
)

print(users)
```

Comment: This helped that was essentially what I was trying to do. Thx